# Connect to a kerberos protected REST in Python using a keytab

Tags: python, kerberos

I am trying to connect to a REST HTTP API protected by Kerberos.
I have found quite a lot of different libraries to do that, but none of them supports using keytabs (all they can do is use a credential cache from OS).

Does someone know a way to easily do that (like plug a path to keytab and principal to get a correct HTTP request) or will I have to manually acquire the token and play with setting headers by hand?

Comment: The keytab is just a file containing a password -- pre-encrypted with a (list of) algorithms(s). First you need to connect to your Kerberos KDC to obtain a TGT _(ticket-granting ticket)_ after authenticating with user (Kerberos UPN i.e. User Principal Name) & password (in your case, the content of the keytab). Then you need to obtain a service ticket for your target HTTP service. Then you need to go through the `SPNego` auth process: HTTP GET without creds / 401 challenge / HTTP GET with service ticket as response to challenge (otherwise similar to 1st attempt) / response.

Comment: Quick and efficient way to do that: run `kinit` to generate the TGT (possibly in a _custom_ cache file set via `$KRB5CCNAME` to make that ticket private and not mess with your default creds), then let the HTTP client lib handle SPNego and generate the service ticket on-the-fly -- any half-serious web client has built-in support for that.

Comment: Well basically I am looking for something that will take care of contacting KDC, obtaining TGT etc. for me. Also I am trying to build a small service that will periodically hit the API, so kinit approach is somewhat dirty. In Java I could just set jaas.conf file to use either cache or keytab, but this options seems to be lacking from any Python library I looked at.

Comment: The Java implementation of Kerberos is partial, and pretty brittle. So don't expect too much of Python...